# jQuery - toggleClass arrow up and arrow down icon change

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I have two containers, each with their own headers and arrow icons to indicate which direction the toggle can take place.

On load, container 1 is open with the up arrow icon (to indicate the content can collapse). On load, container 2 is closed with the down icon (to indicate the content can be expanded).

When I click on either of these, I want to use slideToggle and toggleClass to prevent the other box from closing, allowing the user to see the content within both box and the ability to collapse both.

How would I ensure the arrow icons alternate when clicking each header?

The most important part is having container 1 open on load, and container 2 closed on load. (resulting in opposite icons on load)

Thanks in advance!

```
<xsl:template name="Alert-Wrapper">
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" />
<div id="alert-wrapper">

    <div class="accordion-header expandable-header">
        <span class="accordion-header-style">New Alerts</span>
    </div>


    <div class="alert-item-container expandable-content">
        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
            <xsl:call-template name="alert-items"/>
        </xsl:for-each>    

        <div class="view-more-alerts">
            <a href="www.google.com">
                <span class="view-more-image"><img src="/mountney.co.uk/images/Red-Arrow-View-More.png"></img></span>
                <span class="view-more-text">View more alert items</span>
            </a>
        </div>              
    </div>          
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The following jquery handles the expanding and collapsing of content.

```
    $('.expandable-header').click(function(){

    $(this).next('.expandable-content').slideToggle('slow');    

    });
```

I just need to modify the '.accordion-icon' background image to change (which is the background image of the header)

Comment: addClass / removeClass ? Post some code of what your doing. Welcome to Stack :)

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution, without jQuery animation:

```
$(function(){
  $('.header').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.container').toggleClass('collapsed');
  });
});
```

DEMO using CSS3 transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/AMzfe/

Comment: Thanks Cristy - I've made a few modifications to my original post. The code you provided works great and the icons are changing beautifully. However, if you use slide toggle instead of CSS3, to make the fluid transitions in content appearing, have you noticed that the first time you close the open container, it doesn't slide? It simply disappears? Do you know what causes that? http://jsfiddle.net/MattiusHolden/em37q/